# Add checked to element if its attribute value equals to given string

Tags: jquery, html

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="letter_type" data-custom="Something" value="0">  Something
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="letter_type" data-custom="Something1" value="1"> Something1
    </li> 
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="letter_type" data-custom="Something2" value="2" >  Something2
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
    if ($("input[data-custom='Something1']")) {
        alert(true);
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    }; 
</script>
```

The list is generated by my PHP (in a loop) script, I wonder why is this not working. I need the `Something1` to be checked by default after drawing the list.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bv0egnkk/).

Comment: `$("whatever")` returns jQuery object. It is always `true` when casting to Boolean. What do you really want to test in `if`?

Comment: @Regent I just want to add attribute checked if the data-custom="Something1"

Comment: $(this) was null in this case, that's why it didn't add checked attr.

Comment: I wonder why its down voted -.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an `if`.

```
$("input[data-custom='Something1']").attr( 'checked', true );
```

Comment: Well that works, I got also a new problem, It is not a case to make a new topic imo. Check http://jsfiddle.net/gdy19ksy/1/

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$("input[data-custom='Something1']").prop( 'checked', true );
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bv0egnkk/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the length for `if` as jQuery always returns an object which has `length` property, if it doesn't find the element and an object is *truthy*. Also use `prop` instead of `attr` to set the `checked` value.

```
var elm = $("input[data-custom='Something1']");
if(elm.length){
   alert(true);
   elm.prop('checked', true);
}
```

Comment: Even though `.prop()` is probably better than `.attr()` in this situation, I don't see any need for this `if`. Why not simply `$("input[data-custom='Something1']").prop('checked', true);`?

Comment: What is the use of checking length there?

Comment: downvoting without comment doesn't help the matter.